# JSONConvert.DeseralizeObject won't pass

Tags: c#, json, json.net

i'm trying to run through some JSON seralisation into some objects. pretty straight forward stuff.
for some reason i have the first part working as expected, it seralises perfectly.

the moment i wrap this JSON in an additional element the Deseralize Object passes, but the object is empty... i cannot spot the issue and i cannot seem to debug what's going on here.

```
string UIElement = "{\"Name\":\"X1144\",\"Order\":1,\"Tvalue\":\"int\",\"BindValue\":null,\"Default\":null,\"Disabled\":false,\"Mandatory\":true,\"MandatoryMessage\":\"this is a mandatory field\",\"Label\":\"<B> THIS is a HTML</b> label\",\"ToolTip\":\"just a tooltip\",\"PolicyProcess\":[{\"URL\":\"https://google.com\"}],\"Type\":\"RadzenColorPicker\",\"TypeOptions\":[{\"Name\":\"showHSV\",\"Value\":\"True\"},{\"Name\":\"showRGBA\",\"Value\":\"True\"},{\"Name\":\"ShowColors\",\"Value\":\"True\"},{\"Name\":\"showButton\",\"Value\":\"True\"}],\"ItemsType\":null,\"Items\":[],\"Scorable\":false,\"Score\":0,\"Visibility\":true,\"VisibilitySettings\":{\"Condition\":\"OR\",\"Rules\":[{\"Id\":\"X1234\",\"Value\":\"Yes\"},{\"Id\":\"X1222\",\"Value\":\"Yes\"}]},\"KMRs\":false,\"KMRsSettings\":[],\"Docs\":false,\"DocsSettings\":[],\"AutoFill\":true,\"AutoFillSettings\":{\"Value\":\"#999999\",\"Condition\":\"AND\",\"Rules\":[{\"Id\":\"X1234\",\"Value\":\"No\"},{\"Id\":\"X1234\",\"Value\":\"No\"}]}}";
            RadzenUIElement element = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RadzenUIElement>(UIElement);
            Console.WriteLine("UIElement " + element.Name);
            foreach (var item in element.VisibilitySettings.Rules)
            {
                Console.WriteLine( item.Value.ToString());
            }

            string RadzenPanel = "{\"RadzenPanel\":{\"Id\":\"asfdgsertw34t43t34\",\"RadzenUiElement\":{\"Name\":\"X1144\",\"Order\":1,\"Tvalue\":\"int\",\"BindValue\":null,\"Default\":null,\"Disabled\":false,\"Mandatory\":true,\"MandatoryMessage\":\"this is a mandatory field\",\"Label\":\"<B> THIS is a HTML</b> label\",\"ToolTip\":\"just a tooltip\",\"PolicyProcess\":[{\"URL\":\"https://google.com\"}],\"Type\":\"RadzenColorPicker\",\"TypeOptions\":[{\"Name\":\"showHSV\",\"Value\":\"True\"},{\"Name\":\"showRGBA\",\"Value\":\"True\"},{\"Name\":\"ShowColors\",\"Value\":\"True\"},{\"Name\":\"showButton\",\"Value\":\"True\"}],\"ItemsType\":null,\"Items\":[],\"Scorable\":false,\"Score\":0,\"Visibility\":true,\"VisibilitySettings\":{\"Condition\":\"OR\",\"Rules\":[{\"Id\":\"X1234\",\"Value\":\"Yes\"},{\"Id\":\"X1222\",\"Value\":\"Yes\"}]},\"KMRs\":false,\"KMRsSettings\":[],\"Docs\":false,\"DocsSettings\":[],\"AutoFill\":true,\"AutoFillSettings\":{\"Value\":\"#999999\",\"Condition\":\"AND\",\"Rules\":[{\"Id\":\"X1234\",\"Value\":\"No\"},{\"Id\":\"X1234\",\"Value\":\"No\"}]}}}}";
            RadzenPanel panels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RadzenPanel>(RadzenPanel);
            Console.WriteLine("elements in panels " + panels.Id);
```

the output from this code is below;

```
UIElement X1144
Yes
Yes
elements in panels
```

as i progress i'm looking to enhance the RadzenPanel to hold an array of the UIElements, but right now i cannot get it to parse a single item..

the object structure looks like this;

```
public class RadzenPanel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public RadzenUIElement RadzenUiElement { get; set; }
    }

    public class RadzenUIElement
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string Tvalue { get; set; }
        public string BindValue { get; set; }
        public string Default { get; set; }
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }
        public bool Mandatory { get; set; }
        public string MandatoryMessage { get; set; }
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public string ToolTip { get; set; }
        public PolicyProcessLink[] PolicyProcess{ get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public TypeOptions[] TypeOptions { get; set; }
        public string ItemsType { get; set; }
        public Items[] Items { get; set; }
        public bool Scorable { get; set; }
        public double ContributionScore { get; set; }
        public bool Visibility { get; set; }
        public VisibilitySettings VisibilitySettings { get; set; }
        public bool KMRs { get; set; }
        public KMRsSettings[] KMRsSettings { get; set; }
        public bool Docs { get; set; }
        public DocsSettings[] DocsSettings{ get; set; }
        public bool AutoFill { get; set; }
        public AutoFillSettings AutoFillSettings { get; set; }
    }

    public class PolicyProcessLink
    {
        public string  URL { get; set; }
    }

    public class TypeConstants
    {
        public const string RadzenCheckbox = "RadzenCheckbox";
        public const string RadzenCheckboxList = "RadzenCheckboxList";
        public const string RadzenColorPicker = "RadzenColorPicker";
        public const string RadzenDatePicker = "RadzenDatePicker";
        public const string RadzenDropDown = "RadzenDropDown";

    }
    public class TypeOptions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Items
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string BGColor { get; set; }
        public string TColor { get; set; }
        public bool  IsScore { get; set; }
        public double Score { get; set; }
        public bool IsNa { get; set; }
        public string KMRIndicator{ get; set; }
        public string DocsIncicator { get; set; }
    }

    public class VisibilitySettings
    {
        public bool Value { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public Rules[] Rules { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rules 
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class KMRsSettings
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public double Weighting { get; set; }
    }

    public class DocsSettings
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public double Weighting { get; set; }
    }

    public class AutoFillSettings
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public Rules[] Rules { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you just test, Serializing the Data then instantly Deserializing it, so the string is created in memory and then used? it might be a problem with the string your feeding it and this just rules that out.

Comment: good idea, i'll give it a try (y)

Comment: Just on this note if it does work, try writing out the Serialised result to a text file and then reading it in or copying and pasting it from the text file into a string.

Comment: Your `string RadzenPanel` JSON has an additional layer of object container that does not correspond to your data model: `{ "RadzenPanel" : { /* RadzenPanel properties */ } }`  You need to fix your JSON to correspond to your data model, or add an additional level of nesting to the data model.

Comment: thanks @dbc, i thought it might be something like that, but i'm not sure i spot the issue...

Comment: this is what i have got ```{
 "RadzenPanel":{
  "Id":"asfdgsertw34t43t34",
  "RadzenUiElement":{
   "Name": "X1144",
   "Order": 1,
   "Tvalue": "int",
   "BindValue": null,
   "Default": null,
```

Comment: ultimatly this is what i want to get to;

Comment: {"formbuilder": ......some properties....., "RadzenPanels":[ {"RadzenPanel": ...some properties..., "RadzenUIElements":[ some UI elements ]}]}

Comment: ```public class RadzenFormBuilder
    { 
        public string Id { get;set }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int version { get; set; }
        public RadzenPanel[] RadzenPanels{ get; set; }

    }

    public class RadzenPanel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public RadzenUIElement[] RadzenUiElement { get; set; }
    }

    public class RadzenUIElement
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }```

Comment: GOT IT :) --> ``` {
 "Id":"cx345234253",
 "Name":"fgvsdg345",
 "Version":1,
 "RadzenPanels":[
  {
   "Id":"dsfgsdfgsdf",
   "Name":"dfgssf",
   "RadzenUiElements":[
    {
     "Name": "X1144",
     "Order": 1,
     "Tvalue": "int",
     "BindValue": null,
     "Default": null,'''

Answer (score -1):

not sure what the exact problem was, but i solved it by working through the c# model and progressively built the JSON to suit.

the full debug process started with an approach that debugged the core element. RadzenUiElement (bottom up) followed by building out the wrapper for the whole lot top down.